# Why don't the official FancyBox 4 bind examples work?

Tags: fancybox

None of the bind examples in the documentation work - https://fancyapps.com/docs/ui/fancybox/api

The standard constructor examples work great, but anything that requires binding does not work. There is no error, but the gallery lightbox doesn't work - clicking an image just opens the image as a link. Here is the exact example code with markup:

```
<div id="gallery">
  <a href="https://lipsum.app/id/1/800x600">
    <img src="https://lipsum.app/id/1/300x225" />
  </a>

  <a href="https://lipsum.app/id/2/800x600">
    <img src="https://lipsum.app/id/2/300x225" />
  </a>
</div>

<script>
  Fancybox.bind("#gallery a", {
    on : {
      ready : (fancybox) => {
        console.log(`fancybox #${fancybox.id} is ready!`);
      }
    }
  });
</script>
```

That console log never fires.

I'm importing FancyBox like this:

```
import { Fancybox } from '@fancyapps/ui';
```

I've tried searching around, but very little info on FancyBox 4 other than official docs and it's frustrating as they don't work. I've tried some of the examples in showcase also, and the same deal. If it's binding, it won't work and no errors are shown. Anyone have any insight into this?

Thanks,

Tom

Answer (score 0):

It works perfectly fine. Since you did not provide a live demo (or at least a full HTML code), then it just not possible to help you.

It is so frustrating to read comments like this, no demo, no useful info, nothing. Maybe you did not include JS file, I do not know ... I would love to help you and to improve documentation, but, sorry, your comment is not helpful at all.

Fancybox is designed to be as easy to use as possible, all you have to do is:

1. Include two files - CSS and JS file (to get `Fancybox` object).
2. Add `data-fancybox` attribute to your links (or to call `Fancybox.bind("YOUR_SELECTOR");)`

Thats it! It can not be any simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, it should have been a much clearer question. I didn't include a demo because it's a big wordpress site in production. It was giving me no useful feedback or errors or anything like that. I build websites day in and day out, so assumed it wasn't just me making some incredibly stupid mistake like a typo or something. I genuinely spent a lot of time on this, it wasn't me being lazy and just posting on stack overflow straight away...

It was me being stupid though.

In the process of making a demo to show you, I found the problem and (as you already know!) it's my mistake. I was able to make fancybox work by instantiating it straight away in my js, but binding (and therefore galleries etc) was not working.

The reason was the javascript was included in the head of the html document *before* the markup instead of at the bottom of the html document before the closing body. There was nothing for the js to bind to when it was executed.

I wouldn't normally include javascript in the head either but it's a wordpress project and because of some plugin, it's required there. Fancybox 3 worked with js in the head, but I suspect it might be jquery being more forgiving than native js with it's binding to DOM elements?

So, yes, entirely my fault. I was following the steps of the installation and startup guide almost exactly, but that inclusion of the js file in a slightly unusual (or bad practice at least) place was what caused all the issues.